# Change Progress/Seekbar scale to be non-linear (e.g. logarithmic)

Tags: android, progress-bar, seekbar

Is it possible to change the scaling of Progress- or Seekbars to be non-linear?

If so, how can it be changed?

Comment: I don't know at what you're referring with "scaling". The progess for those widgets is set through `setProgress(progressValue)`, if you want a logarithmic behavior then make sure the values you use with the method `setProgress()` are in a logarithmic series.

Comment: Let's say I set the min to 0, the max to 10,000 . When the user slides the progress bar to 50% the value would be 5,000 , but I want something like 1,000 e.g.

Answer (score 5):

For example:

```
weightSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

// place onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) and onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) here

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        userWeight = ((progress * progress) / (1000.0f * 1000.0f)) * (maxWeight - minWeight) + minWeight; // Approximate an exponential curve with x^2.
        }
    });
```

and vice versa:

```
weightSeekBar.setProgress((int) (Math.sqrt(((userWeight - minWeight) / (maxWeight - minWeight)) * 1000.0f * 1000.0f)));
```